# iphone function

Tags: iphone

i have a code like this
i have defined the method goNext but still m getting a warning "'viewcontrolller' may not respond to 'goNext'". how'll i solve this.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickers 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

statements;

    [self goNext];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your forgot to define it in your .h file?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't define goNext in your header file and only in the .m file, then you need to make sure it's defined above imagePickerController